# Javascript error, not recognizing function... why?

Tags: javascript

This is my code (in a firefox addon)

```
this.something_something = function (the_actual_url) {
    this.this_version = null;
    try {
        // Firefox 4 and later; Mozilla 2 and later
        Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
        AddonManager.getAddonByID("parasites@maafire.com", function (addon) {
            this_version = addon.version;
        });
    }
    catch (ex) {
        // Firefox 3.6 and before; Mozilla 1.9.2 and before
        var em = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExtensionManager);
        var addon = em.getItemForID("parasites@maafire.com");
        this_version = addon.version;
    }


    this.timervar = setTimeout(function () {
        this.get_plugin_version(this.this_version);
    }, 2000);
}

this.get_plugin_version = function (blah) {
    alert("aa:" + blah);
}
```

I get the error:

> Error: this.get_plugin_version is not a function
>   Source File: chrome://mf_monkey_project/content/overlay.js Line: 476

What am I doing wrong?

Sorry about the screwed up formatting, but i deleted the bulk of the code to fit here and it made the formatting all screwy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `setTimeout` callback will be executed in the global context.

You can use the [`bind()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method  to bind the desired context and argument for the callback.

```
this.timervar=setTimeout( this.get_plugin_version.bind(this, this.this_version),
                          2000 );
```

If you don't want the current value of `this.this_version` permanently bound as the first argument, then remove it from the `.bind()` call.

Comment: now I get  `Error: this.get_plugin_version is undefined
Source File: chrome://mf_monkey_project/content/overlay.js
Line: 476`

Comment: @Ryan: Then `this` in your `something_something` function is not the object you're expecting.

Comment: Oops, no, I did an edit instead of copying your code.. it works, but gives me null as the version number :(     any idea why?

Comment: @Ryan: Because `this.this_version = null;`. If `this_version` is being updated within that `2000ms` timer, then remove the `this.this_version` argument from the `.bind()` call. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Now I am getting some funny numbers, like 12 or 2341 or 2343 etc... but not the version number :(

Comment: @Ryan: If the `this` value of `get_plugin_version` is the same object as the `this` value of `this_version`, then change your `get_plugin_version` function to do `alert("aa:" + this.this_version );`